# How to show what enable_outdb_rasters is set to in Postgis

Tags: postgis, raster

I know that you can enable out of database raster support via the query:

```
SET postgis.enable_outdb_rasters TO True;
```

Before running this query I'd like to verify that postgis.enable_outdb_rasters is set to False. Is there a query to show or select what the current postgis.enable_outdb_rasters variable is set to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SHOW postgis.enable_outdb_rasters;
```

**EDIT**: The parameter has to be set before!

Comment: running that query gives: ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "postgis.enable_outdb_rasters"

Comment: I dunno what the deal was, but after setting postgis.enable_outdb_rasters = True in my /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf the query you supplied gives result: True  I guess maybe the param has to be set to something before that query works?

Comment: @apricity Yes, I guess that the parameter has to be set before. Glad it worked out.