# Enabling outdb rasters in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgis, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I have an AWS RDS server connected to PostgreSQL, and I also have some rasters in the cloud (s3 bucket). I want to remotely query them using outdb rasters but I'm not sure how to set enable_outdb_rasters to true.
When I type the command on the session level, it says permission denied even though I'm an rds_superuser. I've also tried finding it in the AWS parameter groups but couldn't find postgis.enable_outdb_rasters. Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/215515/how-to-show-what-enable-outdb-rasters-is-set-to-in-postgis